# HOSTING ASP.NET CORE ON UBUNTU cannot access thru client's browser

Tags: asp.net, ubuntu, kestrel

I badly need your help because I'm trying to create a dummy app for my project on ubuntu server but everytime I run the published .dll file I cant access it on my client pc.

Here's what ive done on my host (VM ubuntu server)

- download dotnet-sdk-2.1
- `dotnet new mvc`
- `dotnet publish -c release`
- copied the published files on /var/www/firstapp

`dotnet firstapp.dll` gives output:

```
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /home/ubuntu/testapp/netcore/publish
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.*
```

I tried to access it on browsers with http://192.168.56.103:5000 (server's ip) but still cannot access.

I have tried to open the port 80, 5000, 50001 it still not connecting. I also tried to disable the firewall. Thank you guys.

Comment: Are the "client PC" and VM on the same network?

Comment: Does it work if you try locally? http://localhost:5000

Comment: we have the cloud VM. I tried but it is not working, so i tried also the create a VM on virtual box with the same network but it is not working :(

Comment: please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48669548/why-does-aspnet-core-start-on-port-80-from-within-docker

Answer (score 1):

please refer to [Why does aspnet core start on port 80 from within Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48669548/why-does-aspnet-core-start-on-port-80-from-within-docker) ，

you can use environment variable to change the  listening ip and port, then run your app:

```
export ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000
dotnet firstapp.dll
```

Comment: i did but nothing happens. btw, i did try to install Links in my server then browse http://localhost:5000 my sample web starts running, but every time i try to browse the public IP which is http://192.168.56.103:5000 i encountering bad server

Comment: what is the console output after you export the environment var?

Comment: I have the same issue and is not running in a vm. Ubuntu installation.