# Change ASP.NET API Docker port for debugging

Tags: asp.net-core

I created an ASP.NETCore API app (.NET 6) and ticked the box to host it in Docker.

The Docker file exposes port 443, and when I run the app in Visual Studio it runs on port 49173. Can someone tell me where I can change that port number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In project folder "**Properties\launchSettings.json**" any debugging configurations such as; environment variables and profiles can be defined there.

*note that the file only for debugging purposes if you add any environment variable here It will not affect published app.*

**An example 'launchSettings.json'**

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:3377",
      "sslPort": 3378
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles": {
    "Dev": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:3377;https://localhost:3378"
    },
    "Prod": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:3377;https://localhost:3378"
    }
  }
}
```

there is also profile for the Debugging on Docker;

```
"DockerDev": {
  "commandName": "Docker",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  },
  "publishAllPorts": true
}
```

more detail: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0#development-and-launchsettingsjson

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ENV instruction to add an environment variable to the service container image from the Dockerfile file and set the `ASPNETCORE_URLS` variable, like this:

[image]

Reference: [ASP.NET Core in a container](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/quickstart-aspnet-core) and [Why does aspnet core start on port 80 from within Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48669548/why-does-aspnet-core-start-on-port-80-from-within-docker/48669703)