# Use wget instead of curl for healthchecks in ASP.NET Core docker images

Tags: asp.net-core, dockerfile, wget, asp.net-core-6.0, health-check

I want to use an ASP.NET Core 6 healthcheck as a docker healthcheck.

The [docs state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-6.0#docker-healthcheck):

> Containers that use images based on Alpine Linux can use the included wget in place of curl

But there is no guidance for that, and as usual getting the docker config "just right" is more of an art than a science.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to specify a healthcheck via the `docker run` CLI, or in a `docker-compose.yml`. I prefer to do it in the `Dockerfile`.

### Configure

First note that the ASP.NET Core [docker images](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-aspnet) by default expose [port 80](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72560052/9971404), not 5000 (so the docs linked in the question are incorrect).

This is the typical way using `curl`, for a non-Alpine image:

```bash
HEALTHCHECK --start-period=30s --interval=5m \
  CMD curl --fail http://localhost:80/healthz || exit 1
```

But `curl` is unavailable in an Alpine image. Instead of installing it, use `wget`:

```bash
HEALTHCHECK --start-period=30s --interval=5m \
  CMD wget --spider --tries=1 --no-verbose http://localhost:80/healthz || exit 1
```

`HEALTHCHECK` switches [documented here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck).

`wget` switches [documented here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget). `--spider` prevents the download of the page (similar to an HTTP HEAD), `--tries=1` allows docker to control the retry logic, `--no-verbose` (instead of `--quiet`) ensures errors are logged by docker so you'll know what went wrong.

### Test

For full status:

```bash
$ docker inspect --format '{{json .State.Health }}' MY_CONTAINER_NAME | jq
```

Or:

```bash
$ docker inspect --format '{{json .State.Health }}' MY_CONTAINER_NAME | jq '.Status'
# "healthy"

$ docker inspect --format '{{json .State.Health }}' MY_CONTAINER_NAME | jq '.Log[].Output'
# "Connecting to localhost:80 (127.0.0.1:80)\nremote file exists\n"
```

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-aspnet images do not contain curl

Comment: This is for using wget, not curl. As stated in the question title.